# How to change android spinner popup animation

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, user-interface, spinner

I want to change the animation of the popup that a spinner creates. In xml I can give the spinner state-based animations through the stateListAnimator attribute, where I give a reference to an .xml file in my res/anim folder. But I can't find an attribute that controls the popup animation.

Is this possible to do in xml, or would I have to use java?

Comment: Assuming you're referring to the dropdown popup, it looks like we can, actually. It's a specialized `PopupWindow` that's instantiated with the same `AttributeSet` that the `Spinner` is, so we can put `PopupWindow` attributes directly on the `<Spinner>` element, or in a `style` for it. Beyond that, it seems that only transitions are used starting with API level 24, so you would need to use those in lieu of classic `anim`s: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-00WeA4FomhVK4cey0KtmxoNrDc1ML-7/view?usp=sharing. That example simply uses to sliding animations instead so that the change is obvious.